# Discord.js problem id member can't sent if is it bot or else

Tags: javascript, discord.js

## Discord.js v.11.4.2

I have a problem I know problem but i don't know how to fix

A problem is someone id in file idmember.txt i think line 39 it can't sent message to that id

How can i fix if i have id more than 1000

If I it have an error I want to be it sent only console.log(`have error ${error}`) and sent message to next member with id

Error code

```js
readline.js:1170
            throw err;
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Source Code

```js
 if(message.content === '!sentid'){
    const readidmem = readline.createInterface({
      input: fs.createReadStream('./idmember.txt'),
      output: process.stdout,
      console: false
    })
    var lineno = 0;
    readidmem.on('line', function (line){
      lineno++;
      console.log('Line number ' + lineno + ': ' + line);
      var idlinemem = line;
      client.users.get(idlinemem).send(Embed);
    })
    try {
      console.log("try")
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

Source Code of idmember.txt

```
460196042411999243
449820309974155265
198685267119308800
454974307471327233
701430850855764060
493820421758648330
286381286556434433
641313479495778305
463690843044315136
624681848911429670
575566960641966081
330589475795369991
443374569986719754
565962829870661632
446979571993280522
396351972040507404
601016374336290836
632739220267597824
462486450445746176
467844027518156800
441935641224282112
452343746407956480
630005338929758219
429249984001736735
407206522167492619
221131388370288642
215573230038155264
498125423549349888
539148660424835077
465228724040892416
469456250241941504
649312937613197353
443400032155205632
470530413123600384
320490292149092352
440799283776716800
707187551219482668
361663051851890688
502280435380781086
695706254613676112
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try putting `try/catch` on top of your `send` method.

```
    readidmem.on('line', function (line){
      lineno++;
      console.log('Line number ' + lineno + ': ' + line);
      var idlinemem = line;
      try {
        client.users.get(idlinemem).send(Embed);
      }
      catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    })
```

So that when the object cannot send, it will not crash your program but only log the error.

Comment: thanks verymuch and can i ask you if in command it have problem suchas error code : 50007 how i snipped it

Comment: if error code 50007 then console.log("Can't sent this user")

Comment: @BeamKunGzMARK You can look into the error object "e" in the catch. You will see something like a status code or something like that. With that, you check using if-else if the error code is 50007 then you log your desired message.